# Mock a C function when unit testing with unity

Tags: c, unit-testing, unity-test-framework

I have a C project with 2 modules - A and B.
B has a function that calls a function from A.

```
int B_func() {
  if (1 == A_func()) {return 1;}
  return 2;
 }
```

I use unity to test these modules.

```
TEST(B, test_b) {
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(1, B_func())
}
```

When I test module B, I want to mock A_func so it will use my implementation and change the return value. Is there a way to do this without changing the source code of module B?

Comment: I don't see your problem. The function is not implemented in B. So why not? (and why mock, just change `A_func`.)

Comment: I don't want to change A_func, since it is already part of the project and is linked in. I want to tell B_func to ignore the original implementation of A_func, i.e to mock A_func in B's unit tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Mimick.
https://github.com/diacritic/Mimick

It's a bit cumbersome. I needed to compile my project as a shared object and link it to my tests so my functions will be in the GOT, so it is not ideal, but successfully solves my problem.